# Generic method returning derived class throws Object must implement IConvertible exception

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class:

```
public class TestBase
{
}
```

I have a derived class

```
public class TestDerived: TestBase
{
}
```

I have a `generic method`

```
  public class SomeClass
  {
   public T GetInstance()
   {
      var inst=new TestDerived();
      return (T)Convert.ChangeType(inst, typeof(T)); //exception thrown here
   }
  }
```

I make a call:

```
    SomeClass test=new SomeClass()
    var x= test.GetInstance<TestBase>();
```

Why do I get an exception saying `System.InvalidCastException : Object must implement IConvertible.`

Comment: Because neither type you have defined implements the `IConvertible` interface.

Comment: But if I make a call `var x= test.GetInstance<TestDerived>();`, it works fine. Shouldn't `polymorphism` "act" here as well?

Comment: Sure, but then that method doesn't have a dependence on `IConvertible`. The original attempt does.

Comment: Yes, like I said, shouldn't polymorphism "act" in such scenario during the conversion?

Comment: Why are you trying to use generics here? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, It is just the simplified version of the problem

Comment: That doesn't help with understanding what you're trying to achieve.  Spoon feed us and we'll be able to give little or no help.

Comment: I was just interested in why doesn't it work. I could change the way I'm using or not use the generic method at all.

Comment: Well as the others said, Convert only acts on IConvertible things, which T isn't.  Hence the error.  Convert isn't for casting.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Negative voter? care to explain?

Comment: I haven't put an answer to this question; only comments. I think you're referring to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

By using constraints you can let the compiler know T is based off TestBase. 
This way you get to avoid losing type checking.

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public T GetInstance() where T : TestBase
   {
      var inst=new TestDerived();
      return inst;
   }
}
```

But why do you need to use generics at all?  There's nothing here that benefits from it.